# How to stop the propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```
$(".btnClose").click(function (e) {
    alert('a');
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#modal-a').modal();
    $("#modal-a .btn-danger").click(function () {
        window.location.href = targetUrl;
    });
});


$('.clickable-row').click(function () {
    alert('b');
    var formId = ...;
    var locked = ...

    if (locked == false) {
        document.location = "a/" + formId;
    }
    else {
        document.location = "b/" + formId;
    }
});
```

```html
<tr class="clickable-row">
    <td><a class="btnClose" href="/c?FormId=40">Close</a></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that when I click any button with the btnClose class, it alerts 'a', shows the modal window, wait for the modal window answer. If I answer with cancel, then it will show 'b' and make an undesired redirection.

I see that stop propagation is not working in this case and I don't know why.

Comment: When I click on the row, I need the app to redirect me to a location. When I click the button inside a row, I need to open a modal window. If I choose cancel, it shouldn't redirect. If I choose OK, I need a redirection to the href link location.

Comment: As I believe that your setup is somehow quirky ... Could you please provide a fiddle, so that the guys here can suggest a better solution than beeing able just poking around with this little excerpt?

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way to fix that, just check the target

```
$('.clickable-row').click(function (e) {

    if ( $(e.target).hasClass('btnClose') ) return;


    // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: This is a solution but I don't know what other classes I will have to avoid and I already have five. So this would've been a great solution for only one class but in my situation it is not.

Comment: @tzortzik - You could just avoid any anchor, as in `$(e.target).is('a')`

Comment: Still not OK because I don't want to have jQuery code in my clickable rows. Doing this will be a bag idea later.

Comment: Uhm, what! You already had an event handler for the rows, all you're doing is filtering the event target ?